# Implementing callbacks between files in C

Tags: c, macros, callback

My program contains the following files: data_handler.c, app.c and callback_struct.h.

data_handler.c retrieves data from functions in app.c, by making callbacks to app.c.

The program should allow the user to define a set of functions with arbitrary names in app.c. The user does this by defining his functions, and associating them with a set of initiated function pointers (ptr_func1, ptr_func2 etc.), found in callback_struct.h.

With this approach I want to eliminate the need of making explicit calls from data_handler.c to the user functions in app.c (so that the code in data_handler.c do not have to be modified if the user changes his function names for example), neither do I want to have to include (#) app.c into data_handler.c.

Clearly there is something I'm not getting here. I would be grateful if someone could help me understand what I'm doing wrong, and perhaps give me some indications on whether or not I'm on the right track with my suggested implementation

See my implementation below:

callback_struct.h:

```
    struct callback_struct{
            int (*ptr_func1)(void);
            int (*ptr_func2)(void);
            // etc...
    };

    extern struct callback_struct user_functions; // should be defined in app.c
```

app.c

```
    #include "callback_struct.h"

    int user_function_func1(void);  
    int user_function_func2(void);  

    struct callback_struct user_functions={
            .ptr_func1 = user_function_func1, 
            .ptr_func2 = user_function_func2,
    };

    int  user_function_func1(void){

        int data = 1; // for example...

        return data;
    }

    int  user_function_func2(void){

        int data = 2; // for example...

        return data;
    } 

    // etc.....
```

data_handler.c

```
    #include "callback_struct.h"

    /*this function makes callbacks to app.c to retrieve data*/
     void get_data(int (*ptr)(void)){

              int retrieved_data=ptr();     
    }

    void main(void){

            get_data(user_functions.ptr_func1);
            get_data(user_functions.ptr_func2);
            // etc....
    }
```

Comment: Use strict prototypes on your callback function pointers in the structure. The `()` notation in C means 'undefined fixed-size argument list' (which means the functions do not include `...` ellipsis in the declarations, but otherwise allows any argument list to be valid).  If the functions take no arguments, use `(void)` — that's different from `()` in C,

Comment: Thank you for the feedback @JonathanLeffler. After changing to strict prototypes I still have problems with the program. Seems to be some other issues with the code as well...

Comment: Except for the `void main()` (which is not valid on Unix systems, which is where I work/test), and the unused variable in `get_data()` which I made used by printing it, the code as shown above seems to work OK for me.

Answer (score 2):

It's only a syntax error. Just replace

```
extern struct user_functions={
```

by

```
struct callback_struct user_functions={
```

in your app.c and it will work.

Comment: Thank you @Marian V. You're correct. I still have problems with running the complete program tho...

Comment: Now you have an extra closing parenthesis in function declarations and definitions (after void).

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a global variable 'extern', you are telling the compiler that this variable is instantiated (and possibly initialized) somewhere else in the code.

Therefore, you should not declare it 'extern' and initialize it in the same line, which is exactly what you did in file app.c.